# Xcode - open a file selection through open quick window in a new tab

Tags: xcode8

Is there a way for me to open the file that I selected through open quick window (command + shift + o) in a new tab ? Currently when I select a file it opens up in the current tab. Is there a way for me to open it up in a new tab ?